# In AngularJS how do I substitute minified javascript files with non-minified files in my development environment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to handle this in AngularJS?

I have an AngularJS app that includes concatenated/minified javascript files, however in my development environment I want to load the non-concatented/non-minified versions of the file. I want this because it is easier to debug the code with non-minified files.

```
<!-- production -->
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script> <!-- contains all concatenated/minified code -->

<!-- dev -->
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

I am not sure how to do this since in AngularJS I couldn't find a conditional mechanism that is suitable. I had thought about using a directive on the each script tag?

I am using Gulp to concat and uglify the files, but I couldn't find a method to accomplish this with Gulp.

PHP is the server-side language.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should consider gulp or grunt

Comment: If not using gulp or grunt, the only real option would be to modify it by hand, which of course is inconvenient.

Comment: Angular does not minify/concatenate your source files. This is normally done by a build process specific to your app. The information you provided is not enough to determine how your build works, so it is difficult to advise how it should be changed.

Comment: How are you creating the minified javascript files? Manually?

Comment: What is your server side technology?  ( Node.js , Java, PHP, .NET ) ?

Comment: How are you determining if it is Production mode or dev mode?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Gulp to concat and uglify. My server-side language is PHP.

Comment: Render a template (probably index.php) where you conditionally add either the minified script and css tags, or development script and css tags. @ntropish's edit looks like a good starting point for gulp. i've used [grunt-ejs-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ejs-render) for this successfully

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "Source Map" to go along with the minified javascript file. The source map can then be used when debugging so you can see the original code. If you are using for example *UglifyJS 2.0* or *Closure Compiler* there is an option of creating a source map when you create the minified javascript.

Fore more information about source maps and debugging: [source maps debugging in Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to to do this in Angular might be to use ngInclude to conditionally load an ngTemplate. It would look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="development">
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="production">
  <script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
</script>

<div id="javascripts" ng-include="dev ? 'development' : 'production'"></div>
```

If you are using $scope in your controller then just set $scope.dev to true to include development JavaScript, or false to use the production file.

Edit: But as others have said you should look into a task runner for this instead. Also, look at environment variables for setting what state the project is in.

Edit 2: As for using Gulp for this you can use the [gulp-html-replace package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace). A task using this package would look like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('replace-js', function(){
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    gulp.src('index.html')
      .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'js': ['js/services.js', 'js/controllers.js', 'js/directives.js']
      }))
  }
});
```

for this html:

```
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

(Edit 3: I noticed you might not use node, the stuff below is node specific so you will have to adjust to your needs)

When you run gulp you will have to set the environment variable, that process.env.NODE_ENV you see in the if statement. Do this by running Gulp like this:

```
set NODE_ENV=production && gulp replace-js
```

This is OS specific so google "set environment variable node YOUR_OS" if it doesn't work.

In your package.json add that script to the scripts key, or add the scripts key if it doesn't exist so it might look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "replace-js": "set NODE_ENV=production && gulp replace-js"
}
```

Then you can just use this command instead of typing all of that out:

```
npm run replace-js
```

I'm just going from memory, and have never used gulp-html-replace so hopefully I didn't make any errors and cause you confusion.

Comment: I can't find an example of how to do this with a task runner like gulp, can you direct me?